# CouchRest to delete document from couchdb

Tags: couchdb

How can I delete a document from couchdb using CouchRest, I have the document id. I guess it is something simple I am missing here.

I tried -

```
    CouchRest.delete("http://localhost:5984/db/docid")
```

It throws an RestClient::ResourceNotFound: 404 Resource Not Found:

Could anybody throw some light on this issue please.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You cannot [delete a document](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/api.html#revisions) without knowing its `_rev`.

Comment: Could you please tell how to delete it after I retrieve the _rev?

Answer (score 1):

I don't use CouchRest, but according to your code, you may append a `_rev` query parameter like this:

```
CouchRest.delete("http://localhost:5984/db/docid?_rev=docrev")
```

Comment: this only worked for me if i remove the _ from ?_rev. This might be a version issue my couch.

Answer (score 0):

In order to delete the document you need to know what its revision number is, and then send this back with the delete request. Easiest way to accomplish this is just to get the whole document and then call destroy on that document:

`CouchRest.database("http://localhost:5984/databasename").get(doc_id).destroy()`

Answer (score 0):

## Access CouchDB

couch = CouchRest.new("http://localhost:5984")

db = couch.database('db-name')

timestamp = Time.now

## Save a document, with ID

db.save_doc('_id' => 'doc', 'name' => 'test', 'date' => timestamp)

## Fetch doc

doc = db.get('doc')
puts doc.inspect # #

## Delete

db.delete_doc(doc)